# can't start IronPython interpreter from DOS prompt

Tags: python

here is the output of my path variable:

I run:

```
U:\>echo %path%
```

`C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:\Program Files\Intel\DMIX;C:\Program Files\NTRU Cryptosystems\NTRU TCG Software Stack\bin\;C:\Program Files\Wave Systems Corp\Gemalto\Access Client\v5\;c:\Program Files\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files\Common Files\Roxio Shared\10.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files\SecureCRT 3.0;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\jZip;C:\Program Files\Perforce;C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.6 for .NET 4.0`

all i get is this:

```
U:\>python
'python' is not recognized as an
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: how do you try to launch ironpython?

Comment: AHA! that's it! I need to say ipy, instead of python

Comment: @Xavier, you can answer this if you'd like the rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no magic in command line call (or nearly no)

it takes the different files in your path variable here the useful is `C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.6 for .NET 4.0` and call any .exe or .bat.

By looking into `C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.6 for .NET 4.0` you should be able to find which program is enable for you

Apparently IronPython has ipy.exe not python.exe

Comment: it's really just the last sentence that answers my question.